# Convention for naming Ruby exceptions

Tags: ruby, api, exception, naming-conventions

I already have quite a number of libraries published. What I haven't decided yet is how to name my exceptions. The Ruby standard library always names the exceptions as such (a noun that is `Exception` or `Error`) - for example

- RuntimeError
- EOFError
- ThreadError

Rails, in contrast, uses shortened exception names, like `RecordInvalid` and so on.

If I write libraries, and most of them are not Rails-related, which naming convention should I use? I must admit that the Rails "shortened names" appeal more to me, because when an exception happens you already *see* that it is an exception or an error of some kind because it pops up in the logs/debugger/stderr.

Comment: I usually tend to omit Error/Exception suffix. But sometimes it fits naturally. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how I do it.

Does the name of the exception make it clear what's wrong?  If yes, you're done.  If not, add an `Error` suffix.

So using your example:

- `ThreadError`: Here `Thread` is already a constant in ruby, and also a poor descriptor of an exceptional state.  So a suffix is needed to denote some generic error in a thread.
- `RecordInvalid`: In this case the name of the exception clearly states what's wrong.  `RecordInvlaidError` would be redundant.

Another way to think of it might be generic vs specific.

- `ThreadError`: Generic error, something bad happened with a thread, don't know exactly what, but it wasn't good.  So this describe some sort of "error" in a "thread".
- `RecordInvalid`: Specific error, this record right here has a specific problem with its data integrity and can't saved.  So the "record" is "invalid", and that's all you need to say.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm in the `Error` camp, but only when it feals natural. Putting `Error` on the end makes it clear what the class is, that it's not a normal object, etc. I find `Exception` a little long for my taste, and lack of suffix too ambiguous.